# Durandal / Knockout - global observable

Tags: knockout.js, durandal

**Context**

In my shell.html I have put a language selection into the header section. It looks like this:

```
    <select class="form-control select2"
      data-bind="options:languages,
      optionsText:'label',
      optionsValue:'code',
      value:selectedLanguage">
    </select>
```

My shell.js:

```
define(['plugins/router', 'durandal/app', 'knockout'], function (router, app, ko) {
    return {
        router: router,
        selectedLanguage: ko.observable(),
        languages: [
            {code: 'cs', label: 'čeština'},
            {code: 'sk', label: 'slovenský'},
            {code: 'en', label: 'english'},
            {code: 'de', label: 'deutsch'},
            {code: 'ru', label: 'русский'}
        ],
        activate: function () {
            return router.map([
               { route: ['', 'dashboard'],      moduleId: 'core/dashboard/pages/index',     title: 'Dashboard',         icon: 'fa fa-dashboard fa-fw',      nav: true },
               { route: 'attributes*details',   moduleId: 'core/attribute/pages/index',     title: 'Attribute',     icon: 'fa fa-puzzle-piece fa-fw',   nav: true, hash: '#/attributes' }
           ]).buildNavigationModel()
             .mapUnknownRoutes('core/dashboard/pages/index', 'not-found')
             .activate();
        }
    };
});
```

When I load other views, this always stays in the header and does not change.

**Task**

Whenever the user changes the language, I want to be able to register/notice this on any sub-page and then react accordingly - like showing the text in another language.

**Question**

I suppose this is more of a conceptual question. If I change the language, then I am sure that my observable in the shell.js will pick this up. What I do not understand is how to achieve this for my sub-views. Do I need to register some global-subscriber?

It is obviously not enough to just react in the shell.js because that view-model does not know which content needs to be loaded. Only the actual sub-views / modules know this. But in order to react, they need to know that the language has changed.

It would be great if someone could help me on this and give me a hint on how to best deal with these type of features in a durandal/knockout context.

**[EDIT] Current Solution**

I have tried a few things out now and this is what I have come up with:

*main.js: creates an AppViewModel and adds it to the global myapp Object (that all pages require).*

```
  define([
          'durandal/system', 
          'durandal/app', 
          'durandal/viewLocator', 
          'plugins/router', 
          'myapp/myapp',
          'myapp/appViewModel'
          ],
    function (
        system, 
        app, 
        viewLocator, 
        router, 
        myapp,
        AppViewModel
    ) {
      system.debug(true);

      // Global view-model which will be required by sub-pages.
      myapp.app = new AppViewModel({
        defaultLanguage: 'cs'
      });

      app.title = 'Control Panel';

      app.configurePlugins({
          router:true,
          dialog: true,
          widget: true
      });

      app.start().then(function() {
          viewLocator.useConvention();
          app.setRoot('shell', 'entrance');
      });
  });
```

*AppViewModel: handles the language events*

```
  //------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Global AppViewModel which holds the current language, 
  // listens for changes and notifies the current sub-page 
  // if is has registered a listener-function.
  //------------------------------------------------------------------
  define([ 'jquery', 'underscore', 'knockout' ], function($, _, ko) {

    "use strict";

    function AppViewModel(options) {

        if (!(this instanceof AppViewModel)) {
            throw new TypeError("AppViewModel constructor cannot be called as a function.");
        }

        this.options = options || {};   

        // Set the initial language.
        this.selectedLanguage = ko.observable(options.defaultLanguage);

        _.bindAll(this, 'languageChanged', 'onLanguageChange');
    }

    AppViewModel.prototype = {
        constructor: AppViewModel,
        //---------------------------------------------------------------
        // Calls listener when language changes. See shell.
        //---------------------------------------------------------------
        languageChanged: function(data, event) {
            if(!_.isNull(this.onLanguageChange)
                && !_.isUndefined(this.onLanguageChange) 
                && _.isFunction(this.onLanguageChange)) {
                this.onLanguageChange(data, event);
            }
        },
        //---------------------------------------------------------------
        // Listener that can be overridden by view-models of sub-pages.
        //---------------------------------------------------------------
        onLanguageChange: function(data, event) {
            // Override by ViewModel.
        },
        //---------------------------------------------------------------
        // Clear() should be called in deactivate callback of the 
        // view-model to stop being notified when the language changes.
        //---------------------------------------------------------------
        clear: function() {
            // Reset to empty function.
            this.onLanguageChange = function(data, event) {}
        }
    }

    return AppViewModel;    
  });
```

*shell.js:*

```
    define(['plugins/router', 'durandal/app', 'knockout', 'underscore', 'myapp/myapp'], function (router, app, ko, _, myapp) {

      return {
          router: router,
          languages: [
              {code: 'cs', label: 'čeština'},
              {code: 'sk', label: 'slovenský'},
              {code: 'en', label: 'english'},
              {code: 'de', label: 'deutsch'},
              {code: 'ru', label: 'русский'}
          ],
          app: myapp.app, // make app available to shell.html for the event handler. 
          activate: function () {
              return router.map([
               { route: ['', 'dashboard'],      moduleId: 'core/dashboard/pages/index',     title: 'Dashboard',         icon: 'fa fa-dashboard fa-fw',      nav: true },
               { route: 'attributes*details',   moduleId: 'core/attribute/pages/index',     title: 'Attribute',     icon: 'fa fa-puzzle-piece fa-fw',   nav: true, hash: '#/attributes' }
           ]).buildNavigationModel()
             .mapUnknownRoutes('core/dashboard/pages/index', 'not-found')
             .activate();
          }
    };
  });
```

*shell.html: languageChanged() is now being called on the global AppViewModel*

```
  <select class="form-control select2"
    data-bind="event: { change: app.languageChanged }, options:languages,
    optionsText:'label',
    optionsValue:'code',
    value:app.selectedLanguage"></select>
```

*And finally, one of the page view-models (which is now notified when the selecbox in the shell.html changes)*

```
  define(['jquery', 'knockout', 'myapp/myapp'], function ($, ko, myapp) {

      return {
        activate: function(data) {

                myapp.app.onLanguageChange = function(data, event) {
                    // Handle language stuff ...
                }
        },
            deactivate : function() {
          // Stop listening for language changes
                myapp.app.clear();
            }
      }
  });
```

Hmm ... I wonder whether anyone reads enough to get to this line. If you do, thanks for your time.

So, is this a feasable way of doing it or is there a more "best practise" durandal way?

**[EDIT] Improved solution with durandal publish/subscribe mechanism:**

*AppViewModel: now just sends message - no need for listener logic.*

```
AppViewModel.prototype = {
    constructor : AppViewModel,
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------
    // Trigger message when language has changed.
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------
    languageChanged : function(data, event) {
        app.trigger('language:change', data);
    }
}
```

*index.js: now just receives message - no need to register listener on the AppViewModel.*

```
  define(['durandal/app', 'jquery', 'knockout'], function (app, $, ko) {

      return {
        _langSubscriber: {},
        activate: function(data) {
            _langSubscriber = app.on('language:change').then(function(language) {
                // Handle language stuff ...
            });
        },
        deactivate : function() {
            _langSubscriber.off();
        }
      }
  });
```

As Eric Taylor pointed out, it is important to unsubscribe again. If you don't you will end up with A LOT of subscriptions and most likely a memory leak.

Best regards,
Michael

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What we did was use a singleton `config` module.  If you're not familiar with singleton versus instance modules in Durandal, then you should know this: If your module returns an object literal, it will be singleton and will remain in memory for the duration of your application's session.

If your module returns a constructor function, then Durandal will use that constructor function to instantiate an instance of the module each time it is visited or composed, and will release the module when it is no longer active.

Consider the following bare-bones `config` module:

```
define('config', ['durandal/app', 'knockout'],
    function (app, ko) {

        var currentUser = ko.observable('tester'),
            languages = ko.observableArray([
                {code: 'cs', label: 'čeština'},
                {code: 'sk', label: 'slovenský'},
                {code: 'en', label: 'english'},
                {code: 'de', label: 'deutsch'},
                {code: 'ru', label: 'русский'}
            ]);
    }

    return {
        currentUser: currentUser,
        languages: languages
    };
);
```

Everywhere throughout your modules that you need access to this information, **you simply require the module**.  Also, make sure that any properties on your `config` module that need to update the UI, or respond to updates *in* the UI, are observables.  So, for example, I noticed that your `languages` property is not an `observableArray`.  It probably needs to be if the UI has to respond to updates in this property.

**Use of the `config` Module**

```
define('someViewModel', ['durandal/app', 'knockout', 'config'],
    function (app, ko, config) {

        var languages = config.languages();
    }
);
```

*Note that I had to use the parentheses on `config.languages()` to de-reference the observable array.*

If your local use of `config.languages()` also needs to be observable, then you would have:

```
var languages = ko.observableArray(config.languages());
```

Instead of the above, you could simply pass the `config` module right back out in your revealing object literal:

```
return {
    config: config
};
```

and then use that module directly in your view.  But I don't know if I like this approach.  My preference is to localize injected modules if I intend to use them in a view.

**ANOTHER APPROACH**

You could also use Durandal's pub/sub to send messages between viewmodels in response to changes in the languages, etc., rather than use the direct-connect of observables.

Either approach is valid; it just depends on your needs.

**RESOURCES**

Take a look at John Papa's course, *Single Page Apps with HTML5, Web API, Knockout and jQuery*, on Pluralsight.  Then, take a look at the Durandal version of John's course: *Single Page Apps JumpStart*.  You will learn a great deal about exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Oh, I spent so much time on editing my post, that I had not seen this yet. I will check it out now, thanks.

Comment: @michaeldd I just updated the post to provide greater clarity.

Comment: Thanks very much for your response. My solution is actually not far off from yours, although yours feels a bit more elegant. One thing I do not understand yet. In my version I added the possibility of adding a listener function to the config object, so that each page can react individually to language changes: myapp.app.onLanguageChange = function(data, event) {// Handle language stuff ... }. Is this how you would handle that too or what would you suggest? config.onLanguageChange = function(data, event) {// Handle language stuff ... }?

Comment: Thanks, missed you again :-).

Comment: @michaeldd No problem.  I think I answered your comment question with my edit.  There are a number of approaches you could take to listen without the notion of `config.onLanguageChange`: Use Durandal's pub/sub, use knockout-postbox (https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-postbox) from the incredible Ryan Niemeyer, or use (as we do) postal.js (https://github.com/postaljs/postal.js) for a full-blown, client-side message bus.

Comment: Eric, thanks - I have gone for the publish/subscribe functionality from durandal and it feels much better than the listener-logic. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome! CAVEAT #1: Make sure you deregister your pub/sub subscription in the #detached function of your module, or if your module in not a viewmodel, that you have some sort of shutdown semantic.  You would deregister with the #off function of the pub/sub API.  If you don't, _you will leak memory_.  CAVEAT #2: As your application grows, you may need to move to a full-blown, client-side message bus, such as postal.js.  We did.

Comment: Thanks, I did implement that in the deactivate callback method. I have updated my post now to reflect the change. I may need the bus sooner or later, but I will try to keep it simple for now. As I am no javascript expert, it took me long enough to get into all the frameworks durandal, knockout, require.js, underscore.js, bootstrap etc ... and then understand how to set up a single page app in javascript. I think I am getting there now though - finally.

Comment: Previous commment too long:

I will check out the "Single Page Apps JumpStart" from pluralsight that you mentioned. Hopefully that will clear some things up even further. For now I just need  to think of a better name than _langSubscriber, but that is another story :-). Thanks again.

Comment: @michaeldd CAVEAT #3: In re-reading one of your comments, I should warn again on a different point: Make sure you unit-test your deregistrations.  Singleton modules reside in memory for the duration of the session.  So #deactivate and #detached may never fire.  Same goes for instance modules that are dynamically composed with Knockout's `visible` binding.  The `visible` binding simply hides a module; it does _not_ remove it from the DOM; therefore, #deactivate and #detached will never fire.

Comment: Thanks Eric, I will look into it. Would this be a good way of unit-testing my durandal-code or would you suggest something else? http://blog.tyrsius.com/durandal-testing/

Comment: @michaeldd I'm familiar only with the contours of Jasmine, not with the practicability of it.  I use QUnit myself.  But I would say that I don't think of testing _Durandal_ code, per se.  I simply approach unit-testing from the standpoint of JavaScript.  Since the components of my viewmodels have, themselves, been factored, I don't see a gain in testing the viewmodel itself.  But that's just my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for you tip again. Without your opinion, I would not have another option to look into, so thanks for that. After a quick glance, QUnit looks like the fit and there probably isn't much point in testing view-models.

Comment: Hi Eric, I have had to integrate postal.js sooner than I intended to and it works like a charm. Also very easy to get started. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Hi Michael, At least you did early on!  I stubbornly held on to just pub/sub, and really worked my way into a corner.